# What means "reír sin gracia" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, gramática, significado, inglés

Is like when the person lets out a small laugh without emotion but without being rude?

Laugh unfunny, laugh gracelessly, laugh with no emotion or laugh sarcastically?

Example:

> Maria rio sin gracia y comenzó a hablar.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me the meaning of "reir sin gracia" is couched in circumstance and context.

"Sin gracia" may elicit a lack of humor, emotion, or sarcasm. This lack, if not rude, suggests irony. In English, these attitudes or emotions are well rendered by the term "mirthless". When one laughs "mirthlessly", the attitude is ironic.